# How to POST JSON data using ColdFusion 10 with Rest Services?

Tags: api, rest, web-services, coldfusion-10

I am using ColdFusion 10. I have registered one rest service in ColdFusion Administrator by just adding path to my cfc and service mappings in the rest services tab. I am able to simply GET the data.

Similar to this I wanted a simple example to POST the JSON data but I am having issues doing that. I am using code below and trying to POST the data.

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="restService"> 
<cffunction name="postData" access="remote" returntype="any" produces="application/json"  httpmethod="POST">
    <cfsavecontent variable="JSONData">
    {
     "customer": {
       "first_name": "Steve",
       "last_name": "Lastnameson",
       "email": "steve.lastnameson@example.com",
       "phone": "+15142546011",
       "verified_email": true,
       "addresses": [
         {
       "address1": "123 Oak St",
       "city": "Ottawa",
       "province": "ON",
       "phone": "555-1212",
       "zip": "123 ABC",
       "last_name": "Lastnameson",
       "first_name": "Mother",
       "country": "CA"
         }
       ]
     }
    }
    </cfsavecontent>
    
    <cfhttp url="http://localhost:8080/rest/restApp/restService" method="post" timeout="300" result="httpResponsePosttest">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/json" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#Len(Trim(JSONData))#" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#Trim(JSONData)#" />
    </cfhttp>
    
    <cfreturn httpResponsePosttest>
    
</cffunction>
```

When I tried to dump httpResponsePosttest I am getting this with blank error message and making it hard to debug.
When I tried to hit the same URL in postman with method as POST I am getting "The request has exceeded the allowable time limit tag" as a response.

Can somebody please help me out with this?

Comment: Guys please help me on this.

Comment: I assume you solved this by now. For future reference, always include the main `[coldfusion]` tag too as it gets more visibility.